# Creating a new pandas Dataframe from CSV file with no header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new dataframe from csv:

```
frame = DataFrame(data=pd.read_csv(path))
```

the result is correct except that the first line becomes the columns:

[image]

so I add columns to the dtaframe:

```
columns = ['person-id','time-stamp','loc-id']
frame = DataFrame(data=pd.read_csv(path),columns=columns)
```

then it goes wrong:the dataframe is all nan

[image]

this confuses me,can anyone tell me what is going on with it?

Comment: I've embedded your images for you. But, they are both the same, I don't think that is your intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need `DataFrame` constructor, because output of [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) is obviously `DataFrame` (if not use `squeeze=True`, then `Series`):

```
frame=pd.read_csv(path)
```

Comment: that's a rapid bingo! so what is the problem with my expression?

Comment: Hmmm, first it seems same output and `read_csv` by default first row of `csv` convert to columns. So I am not sure what do you need exactly.

Comment: I had some mistakes adding a image,now it's fixed.would check it for me again? Why does dataframe turn nan?

Comment: It is another solution, but simply use `frame = pd.read_csv(path, names=['person-id','time-stamp','loc-id'])`. I have same solution too, but then overwrite.

Comment: i get it. will be more careful when creating dataframe from csv

Comment: Exactly. There many parameters and one of them is `name`, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#column-and-index-locations-and-names)

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell `read_csv()` that your input has no column headers; by the time you give `Dataframe` the column names, it's too late.  Try this:

```
columns = ['person-id','time-stamp','loc-id']    
frame = pd.read_csv(path, names=columns)
```